# Exlpode effect in jquery cycle fx

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Hello can any one tell me a way to set explode/implode type effect http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/ in the transition of Jquery cycle

What I am saying is how can I add a custom FX in jquery cycle?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to port the explode effect and rewrite it so that jquery cycle can use it.

Code for Explode: http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.effects.explode.js
Dependency: http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.effects.core.js

```
$.fn.cycle.transitions.explode = function($cont, $slides, opts) { 
    var $el = $($slides[0]); 
    // your code here
};

$('#slide').cycle({fx: 'explode'});
```

Reference Example on plugin page:  http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/adv2.html